# why pointer->data works , whereas *double_pointer->data doesn't?

Tags: c++

I have a class 'node' which has two members data and *next. When I am accessing data using pointer then it is working fine whereas when i am accessing it using double pointer , it is throwing an error . Can anyone explain me why this is happening?

```
class node{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
};

push(&a,8);

void push(node **p , int x){
*p->data = 11;
}
```

Why this *p->data showing error:
request for member ‘data’ in ‘* p’, which is of pointer type ‘node*’

Comment: It's an issue of [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 3):

Because `*p->data` is `*(p->data)`, not `(*p)->data`.

Read about [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Can't believe it is not a duplicate of a duplicate.

Comment: N.B. an online tool for this [sort of exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56464040/560648)